# R string cleaning

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub, data-cleaning

I working with some strings that is very messy as shown below

```
 Value
 -------------------
 25 
 32.12 .  (05- 
 33.90 ,
 46.70 ,
 () 26.60
 27.2  
 23.24 .  (12-
 36.52 ,
 27.1814404432133 [
 29.73 .  (22-
 31.8058003525076 [
 35.40 ,
 38.44 . 
 46.14 ,
 29.26 [
 25.44 .
```

I am not sure how to clean this efficiently such that this looks like this.

```
 Value
 -------------------
 25 
 32.12  
 33.90
 46.70
 26.60
 27.2  
 23.24
 36.52
 27.1814404432133
 29.73
 31.8058003525076
 35.40
 38.44
 46.14
 29.26
 25.44
```

I tried using sub function, `sub(" .*", '', Value)` to capture everything before space but that did not work, so looking for some suggestions or tips on how to clean this string.

```
Value <- c(" 25 \n", "  32.12 .  (05-", "33.90 ,\n", "46.70 ,\n", " () 26.60 ", 
           " 27.2  ", "  23.24 .  (12-", "36.52 ,\n", " 27.1814404432133\n\n[", 
           "  29.73 .  (22-", " 31.8058003525076\n\n[", "35.40 ,\n", "  38.44 .\n", 
           "46.14 ,\n", " 29.26\n\n[", "  25.44 .\n")
df <- data.frame(Value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may extract the first number using

```
Value <- c(" 25 \n", "  32.12 .  (05-", "33.90 ,\n", "46.70 ,\n", " () 26.60 ", 
           " 27.2  ", "  23.24 .  (12-", "36.52 ,\n", " 27.1814404432133\n\n[", 
           "  29.73 .  (22-", " 31.8058003525076\n\n[", "35.40 ,\n", "  38.44 .\n", 
           "46.14 ,\n", " 29.26\n\n[", "  25.44 .\n")
df <- data.frame(Value) 
df$Value <- sub(".*?(\\d[0-9.]*).*", "\\1", df$Value)
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/ciYcid)

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(\\d[0-9.]*)` - Group 1 capturing any digit (`\\d`) and then 0+ digits or `.` symbols
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the string.

The `sub` function performs a single replacement with the `\1` backreference holding the value captured into Group 1.

If you want to make sure you only extract digit(s) + ( `.` + digit(s) ) * pattern, you may use

```
df$Value <- sub(".*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", df$Value)
```

See [this R demo](http://ideone.com/8DakIR)

Comment: ah, I tried sub(".*?(\\[0-9.]*).*", "\\1", df$Value) option in the past but missed some parameters now I know what was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library("stringr")

str_extract(df$Value, "(\\d|\\.)+")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(df$Value, regexpr("[0-9][0-9.]*", df$Value)))
```